# Should I edit my flawed but accepted answer

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, wrong-answers

When i wrote my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25386981/android-thread-infinite-loop-phone-overheating/25387010#25387010) question, I did not realise how a `BlockingQueue` worked. I was going to sort it out back then, but forgot. Until now.

Now it is obvious to me, that in the context of the question, my answer is flawed. So should I improve my answer with an edit, or create a new more precise answer?

I found [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265448/should-i-update-my-already-accepted-answer-with-improved-code) on meta, but in that question we are talking about improving an answer. In my case i think the accepted answer is incorrect. I did not manage to find any guidelines for this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Either accordingly to [the answer on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265448/should-i-update-my-already-accepted-answer-with-improved-code) you provided or independently, it is up to you.

My personal opinion and etiquette says: ***"Yes, for sure"***. I think the author wouldn't cancel accepting your answer after you improve it, but if you provide a better answer with the explanation of your research I think the community will appreciate it and you might even receive some upvotes in the future.

If you leave it as it is, it is not helpful to people, moreover someone who knows the correct answer might downvote it because it is wrong.

Comment: You can also add something like "I improved this answer, click the 'edited' link below to see the older version", if you think that that older version might be useful.

Comment: @JonasCz this is think is the best way to do it. My problem was that I also wanted the user to be notified of the fact that the anwer was wrong.

Comment: @john You can always leave a comment stating that you made an update with an "@username" ping. They will get a notification and can come check out your updates. I've done this a few times and it seems to work well.

Answer (score -5):

Do not substantially edit a post that has already been substantially voted upon, let alone accepted. That's quietly and fundamentally misrepresenting the view of everyone who contributed to the answer having those votes and that state.

You *should* comment to the OP instructing them that you no longer believe your answer to be accurate, and inviting them to revise their decision. If they do not respond, you're kind of out of luck really unless you can persuade all your subject-domain friends to downvote the heck out of you.

Don't forget you can also post a new answer with your new view on the question.

Remember, the accepted answer is the one that the OP thinks helped the OP the most, not necessarily the "most right" answer. That's a flawed concept, to be sure but, being the way it is, it's not really up to you or anyone else to dictate which answer that is.

Comment: The edit does not have to change the original content. Just needs to start with __Update__ or something similar. I go back and update old answers but I usually never remove old text. Just add to it.

Comment: @Matt: I hate that. Makes SO look like some sort of Facebook timeline/feed. Good edits should be incorporated into the prose to result in a polished, finished, product. Bad edits should not be made. Yes, this means that most edits that do get made should be fairly insignificant.

Comment: _"You should comment to the OP"_ And probably add a short warning notice on the top the the flawed answer pointing to the "right one" ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux: Okay, to be fair, maybe a warning edited in to the post wouldn't be so bad. I'll give you guys that. :)

Comment: If an answer includes an obviously-broken chunk of code, and a working chunk of code, I don't consider keeping the broken code present defensible just because someone clicked a checkbox -- that's deferring to the OP to the point of making SO a less useful resource for all future viewers.